# Limit law proof for exponentiation

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-writing

How can I prove the following limit law?

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \left(f(x)^{g(x)}\right) =  \lim_{x\to \infty} (f(x))^{\lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)}$$

Thank you, for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a= \lim_{x\to \infty}g(x)$ and $b= \lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)>0$.

Then $g(x) \ln (f(x)) \to a \ln b$ for $x \to \infty$.

Hence $f(x)^{g(x)}= e^{g(x) \ln (fx))} \to e^{a \ln b}=b^a$ for $x \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)^{g(x)}=exp(g(x)ln(f(x))$ since $exp$ and $ln$ are continuous, we deduce that:
$lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}exp(ln(f(x))g(x))=exp(ln(lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x))lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x))= {lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)}^{lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}g(x)}$.